# Ajax Post Multiple Objects to WebApi 2

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

i am passing the JavaScript array objects through ajax post to my web API 2 below is my code, i am getting null value in my web API

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var Contacts = { steve: {},bill: {}, RON: {}, dan: {}, };
    Contacts.bill = {  Name: "Bill", UserName: "Gates",  MobileNUmber: "(206) 555-5555",};
    Contacts.steve = { Name: "Steve", UserName: "Jobs",   MobileNUmber: "(408) 555-1111",};
    Contacts.jon = {  Name: "Steve",  UserName: "Jobs",  MobileNUmber: "(408) 555-2222", };
    Contacts.RON = { Name: "Steve", UserName: "Jobs", MobileNUmber: "(408) 333-5555", };
    Contacts.dan = {  Name: "Steve", UserName: "Jobs", MobileNUmber: "(408) 444-5555",};
    Contacts.qwe = { Name: "Steve", UserName: "Jobs", MobileNUmber: "(408) 555-5555",};
    var ContactList =  JSON.stringify(Contacts)
    console.log(ContactList);
    var baseUrl = "http://localhost:55942/";

          $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: ContactList,
        url: baseUrl + 'api/CONTACT/comparecontacts',
    contentType: "application/json"
});
});
</script>
```

// WEB API I am getting Null value in my Contact list //

```
    public class CONTACTController : ApiController
   {
    [HttpPost]
    public  IHttpActionResult comparecontacts(List<ContactList> ContactList)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not posting an array of contacts. You are posting an object with property names of the different contacts. Try changing your js to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var contacts = [];
    contacts.push({ Name: "Bill", UserName: "Gates", MobileNUmber: "(206) 555-5555", });
    contacts.push({ Name: "Steve", UserName: "Jobs", MobileNUmber: "(408) 555-1111", });

    //..

    var baseUrl = "http://localhost:55942/";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(contacts),
        url: baseUrl + 'api/CONTACT/comparecontacts',
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
});
```